# How to redo an action indefinitely if condition is not met?

Tags: c++, arrays, input, element

So, here's my code:

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
int n;
int a[10];
int main()
{    
    cout<<"Insert amount of data\n";
    cin>>n;

    for (int i=0; i < n; i++){
    cout<<"Insert number (1, 2, or 3)= ";
    cin>>a[i];
    
    if (a[i]<1 || a[i]>3){
    cout<<"Please insert only the number 1-3\n";
    cout<<"Insert number (1, 2, or 3)= ";
    cin>>a[i];
        }
    }
    for (int i=0; i<n;i++) {
        cout<<a[i];
        
    }
}
```

I'm trying to make it so that the program loops until the number 1-3 is typed. However, it doesn't work the way I want it to. For example, if I input `5`, it will output:

```
Please insert only the number 1-3
Insert number (1, 2, or 3)=
```

This is correct. However, if I input `5` again, it gets inputted into the array. I only want the array to have the number 1-3. So, how do I make the if statement loop until the number 1-3 is typed?

Comment: To loop until you get a valid value, you could use a loop construct:  `for`, or `while` or `do...while`.  Or you could use a `goto`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have mastered `for` loops that uses a condition already, so lets add a [`do-while-loop`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/do) loop

Instead of:

```
cout<<"Insert number (1, 2, or 3)= ";
cin>>a[i];
```

You could do:

```
do {
    cout<<"Insert number (1, 2, or 3)= ";
    cin>>a[i];
} while(a[i] < 1 || a[i] > 3);
```

You chould also add error checking. If the user closes the input stream, your program will spin forever.

```
do {
    cout<<"Insert number (1, 2, or 3)= ";
    if(not (cin>>a[i])) return 1; // failed to read an int, abort the program
} while(a[i] < 1 || a[i] > 3);
```